# Winforms datagrid default values

Tags: winforms, datagridview

This drives me crazy:

i'm using a datagridview (bound to a dataset) and textboxes **also** bound to the dataset (which means that everything typed into the textboxes is reflected in the datagridview). The datagridview is actually used only to show up the values (user is NOT able to edit anything in the cells).

So: when the user pushes the add new record button (automatically created by visual studio using binding navigator etc. ) i would like to programmatically select this new line (remember: user has not the ability to select with the mouse) and insert some values.

I tried to use the

```
DefaultValuesNeeded
```

event, but this is firing only if the user selects the row with the asterisk indicator (what the user is not allowed to do).

How can i simulate that behavior? Should i take another approach?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Was searching for alternatives to how I currently do this and just wanted to let you know about a couple ways I know of. Both of these will set defaults when using the `*` (new row) or using a `BindingNavigator`.

```
private void CityBindingSource_AddingNew(object sender,
    AddingNewEventArgs e)
{
    // Simply set the default value to the next viable ID,
    // will automatically set the value when needed.
    locationDataSet.CITY.CITY_IDColumn.DefaultValue =
        CityTableAdapter.GetNewID(); // ++maxID;
}
```

**Or**

```
private void CityDataGridView_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender,
    DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // Gets called when datagridview's */NewRow is entered.
    e.Row.Cells[0].Value = CityTableAdapter.GetNewID(); // ++maxID;
}    

private void bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(object sender,
    EventArgs e)
{
    // BindingNavigator button's AddNewItem automatic tie-
    // in to bindingSource's AddNew() is removed.
    // This sets the current cell to the NewRow's cell to trigger
    // DefaultValuesNeeded event.
    CityDataGridView.CurrentCell =
        CityDataGridView.Rows[CityDataGridView.NewRowIndex].Cells[1];
}
```

**I was really hoping to use this:**

```
private void CityBindingSource_AddingNew(object sender,
    AddingNewEventArgs e)
{
    // Cast your strongly-typed
    // bindingsource List to a DataView and add a new DataRowView
    DataRowView rowView =
         ((DataView)CityBindingSource.List).AddNew();
    var newRow = (LocationDTSDataSet.CITYRow)rowView.Row;
    newRow.CITY_ID = CityTableAdapter.GetNewID();
    newRow.CMMT_TXT = "Whatever defaults I want";
    e.NewObject = rowView;
}
```

But when adding using the `BindingNavigator` or any code based `bindingSource.AddNew()` it results in just a blank row. Hopefully someone finds a better way, but this is working for me so far.

Answer (score 1):

Revised:

How about the [Datatable's TableNewRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.tablenewrow%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) event, then? If that gets fired when the BindingNavigator creates a new row, then that's an opportunity to populate the object.

Comment: Hi Stuart!Thanks for the response. As the documentation correctly states "You cannot set the NewObject property when bound to a DataView or DataTable because you cannot add a new DataRowView to the list." this is the tricky part which gives me the headache (i use a dataset with data tables)!

Comment: That looks better! I will give this a try and let you know! Thanks