# "Add new row"-Button and the DefaultValuesNeeded Event

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have the event `DefaultValuesNeeded`. MSDN says:

> Occurs when the user enters the row for new records so that it can be populated with default values.

When a user CLICKS in the DGV the Default values are set and the dataset can be send to the database.

BUT when a user clicks the button `"Add new row`" (automatically generated by the Navigator) apparentely this doesnt count as "`when the user enters the row`" since the default values are not set.

Any idea how I can combine the "Add new row" Click_event with the DefaultValuesNeeded_Event?

What I tried:

```
Dim i As Integer = DataGridView.Rows.GetLastRow(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible)
DataGridView.Rows(i).Cells("ID").Value = User.GetID()
```

but is still get the same error.

I also tried:

```
Private Sub BindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Click
    BenutzerTabelle_SelectDataGridView.CurrentCell = DataGridView.Rows(DataGridView.NewRowIndex).Cells(0)
End Sub
```

Same error too.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Error is that the dataset cannot be written in the database since default values are missing. There is another topic here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950526/winforms-datagrid-default-values but none of the workarounds are workin for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the best way solving this problem is to use

```
dataset.datatable.relevant_column.defaultvalue = 'Whatever the default value is'
```

I put this into the `form_load event`.

It is even possible to add userspecific information as windows user name.